# Cant migrate changed models.py initial - django

Tags: python, django

I created a new django project. I have a models.py file. I added a handful tables to the file. Now I am trying to migrate it so that I can start updating the project. I am trying to run the following lines but it is saying that there are no changes detected even though the file has changed.

```
Comars-mbp:Yap omarjandali$ python3 manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected
omars-mbp:Yap omarjandali$ python3 manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
omars-mbp:Yap omarjandali$
omars-mbp:Yap omarjandali$ python3 manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
November 08, 2017 - 02:52:28
Django version 1.11.5, using settings 'Yap.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

this is the table added to the models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django_localflavor_us.models import USStateField

#--------------------------------
# the following are tables realted to the app and general information
#--------------------------------

# Profile saves every users profile information
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # server
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, default='first')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, default='last')
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=220, default='bio')
    dob = models.DateField(default='1950-01-01')
    street = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='street address')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='city')
    state = USStateField(default='CA')
    zip_code = models.IntegerField(default=12345)
    phone = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)  # user
    balance = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=9, default=0)
    dwolla_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='https://api-sandbox.dwolla.com')
    synapse_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='123456789')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)  # server
```

Comment: have you add your app into `INSTALLED_APPS` settings?

Comment: make sure it's in the `INSTALLED_APPS` and try adding application name at the end of the command.

Comment: Ok it worked thank you so much. I forgot I have to do that for the project